# How to handle double quotes in Excel column in SSIS?

Tags: excel, ssis, ssis-2016

I have a text in Excel like this {sampletext C" (USD"}
When i am trying to open the excel in notepad then am getting the data like this
{"sampletext "C" (USD"} and then i set the delimiter as none.
now am getting the data like {"sampletext "C" (USD"}
but i need the Excel value into Database like 
{sampletext C" (USD"}..
could you please help anyone that how to handle these datas?

Comment: why'd you open excel in notepad? you can set delimiter in ssis as well.

Comment: @PrabhatG Yes,but if am using the delimiter as " then am getting error like Error: The column delimiter for column "Security Description" was not found.

Comment: not sure if i can help without sample data/ data file. you can try `imex` like this : https://www.concentra.co.uk/blog/why-ssis-always-gets-excel-data-types-wrong-and-how-to-fix-it